Python Discord Bot: Github broke my bot's start command
I'm working on a discord bot in python in Visual Studio Code. I went on vacation about a week ago and uploaded my current code to github before I left with the intent of working on it when I had some downtime, which I didn't end up doing. Returning home and attempting to run the bot, my bot would load everything from my cogs folder, the bot would start running, but it wouldn't respond to any commands. No error messages, nothing. After a while, the bot would just go offline. Debug text in the terminal
After multiple hours of trying to debug, I copied the code into a new .py file that wasn't uploaded to Github, and low and behold, it works just fine, with commands and all.
Original main.py uploaded to github
New main file I just made
Debug Cog file
Does anyone know what happened? I'm insanely confused.

Please, avoid posting code in images

The most likely thing that happened is that your initial file had code that didn't work. GitHub won't make any changes in your file just because. Are you sure the file ran without errors before you pushed it to your GitHub repo?
